# Why the code written below is giving this output?

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

I wrote a code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a[3][3] = {{1, 2, 7}, {3, 4, 9}, {5, 6, 7}};
    int temp;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            temp = a[i][j];
            a[i][j] = a[j][i];
            a[j][i] = temp;
            printf("%d", a[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[I was expecting this output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rPnkh.png).
[But, I am getting this output.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NFqo5.png)

I want to know what's the problem with my code ? [Why it is producing this output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yF6QK.png)

Comment: You're swapping everything twice, so it goes back to the original order.

Comment: Please post code, data, and results as text, not screenshots ([how to format code in posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)). [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: E.g. when `i = 0, j = 1` you swap `a[0][1]` with `a[1][0]`. Then when `i = 1, j = 0`, you swap `a[1][0]` with `a[0][1]`. That undoes the first swap.

Comment: @Barmar: They are not swapping everything twice. Each element on the diagonal is swapped with itself only once. Although that is one time more than they need to be swapped. But this does not explain their problem. The output is not the original order or content of the data. Where does the 2 go? Why do they expect an 8 when there is no 8 to start with?

Comment: seeing as how you don't have 8 in your original array, it's going to be awfully hard to print that out without adding/subtracting from one of the values. Furthermore, you're not printing spaces between your numbers as shown in the output. Please provide the code you're _actually_ running with in the question.

Comment: "but I am getting this output" ... you have a typo in the array data, which has two `7`s and no `8`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want your code to transpose the array, but there are at least three problems:

- When transposing an array, each element off the diagonal is swapped with an element in a reflected position. For example, the element at `[1, 2]` will be swapped with the element at `[2, 1]`. The loops for this should iterate only through each reflected pair once. Your loops iterate through every element in the array, so they hit each pair twice (once for `[1, 2]` and again for `[2, 1]`) and also hit the diagonal elements (which do not need to be swapped at all). A common way to iterate is to use `for (int j = 0; j < i; ++j)`, which hits each pair only once, for the element with the lower `j` coordinate. Variations are possible.
- Your code prints as it moves elements, so it shows work in progress, not the final result. This is why some values, like 3, appear twice in the output and others do not appear at all.
- Your expected output shows “8”, but there is no 8 in the data. And the data is not in an order where transposing it would produce the order shown in your expected output.